# List contents of Windows 10 Start

Tags: powershell, windows-10

In versions of Windows before Windows 10, you could use

```
'%AppData%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\StartMenu'
```

and

```
'%AppData%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar'
```

to see the LNK files of things that had been user pinned.
In Windows 10 this still works for the TaskBar, but the StartMenu folder seems to only contain a `desktop.ini` file, even when things are Pinned to Start.
Have we just lost the ability to see what's pinned in Windows 10, or have they just moved where that stuff lives without removing the now extraneous folder?

Comment: There's a database file somewhere that uses an undocumented format.

Comment: try powershell  Export-StartLayout

Comment: @Antony, that only works at initial setup. The goal here is to be able to advertise newly installed programs on the taskbar, while leaving the user able to delete them if they want. And new software (at least in AEC) is a regular occurrence, happing a good 100 times more often than initial machine setup. I do know that MS has decided that's a bad idea, and for most crappy developers who let their marketing hacks make these decisions, that's true. But for a IT manager to not be able to do it is just dumb.

Comment: @Gordon do you mean the Mobile Device Management (MDM) Settings > Personalization > Start > Show recently added apps  as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/windows-10-start-layout-options-and-policies

Comment: @Antony, no I mean the Start layout. For a number of years I have "advertised" newly installed and commonly used programs in the TaskBar, and newly installed but less often used programs at the top of the Start Menu. Trying to find a way to keep doing something similar in Windows 10, but 1: The Windows 10 UI is a shitshow, and 2: Microsoft seems to not want anyone making the new UI less of a shitshow. Super frustrating.